# How to return date with milliseconds from seconds?

Tags: php

I currently have a time string that is the total amount of seconds and milliseconds, e.g. "83.555" seconds. For my query I need this formatted to "00:01:23.555", so I as of now I was using

```
date("H:i:s.u", 83.555);
```

but I just realized this would output `00:01:23.000000`

Is there any way to properly format the time string?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use the `DateTime` object instead of the `date()` function. Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) "Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds."

Comment: when using `DateTime` with seconds it will result in `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (83) at position 0 (8): Unexpected character`. It seems to only format date times and not seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `DateTime` object instead of the `date()` function. `date()` takes an integer so it discards everything after the decimal. `DateTime` does support fractions of a second.

To generate the `DateTime` object you need to tell it the format you're parsing. Then you can format however you need.

```
Datetime::createFromFormat('s.u', 83.555)->format('H:i:s.u');
```

will return

```
"00:01:23.555000"
```